# how to open row at the same index in ng-repeat , nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and facing an issue with ng-repeat. A list of invoices repeated with ng-repeat, each invoice has List of Payments. I'm trying to get the payments on click of one of the repeated row and then another and so on.

when I open the first one it opens with exact data, when we open other row payments it opens with new payments by replacing the old one. Both payments of the First row payments and second row payments are same.

List of payments has to open with ng-repeat of that particular index. it has to happen for every invoice which is not happening with following

> here is my html

```
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="invoice in relatedInvoices>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-bottom-border">
                            {{invoice.PayableCurrencyCode}} {{invoice.PayablePaidAmount | number: 2}}<br />
                            <small>
                                <a data-ng-click="isOpenPayablePayments[$index] = !isOpenPayablePayments[$index]; togglePayablePayments(invoice.PayableInvoiceId)">Paid</a>
                            </small>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-show="isOpenPayablePayments[$index]">
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Transaction Id</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="payment in payablePayments">
                                    <td>{{payment.TransactionId}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

> Here is my javascript

```
    var getPayments = function (invoiceId) {
        paymentService.getPayments(invoiceId).then(function (paymentsResponse) {
            return paymentsResponse.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.togglePayablePayments = function(invoiceId) {
        $scope.payablePayments = getPayments(invoiceId);
    };
```

Every time on toggle click payments getting replaced with new payments. My problem is how to maintain the payments of particular index of every click and show at respective index. please help me out

Comment: could you please provide us example data for the `relatedInvoices` and `payablePayments`?

Comment: both are arrays, there are list of payments for for one invoice, I want to open particular invoice payments, of any invoice, If I want to open the other invoice payments first invoice payments got replaced with next opened one and so on if we open all one by one last opened invoice payments will be the payments of all repeated invoices.

Comment: created pluknr for the above issue with the names object as invoices, cities as payments in my example. please help me out http://plnkr.co/edit/omBL2czm9fRBEVIeQUyD?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/r3BUbd1LsgMEyyOy5q1z?p=preview)

```
<tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="city in name.cities">
             <td>{{city.city}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Actually you have to specifies main object name with the cities. `name.cities`

That's all !!!

Hope this will help you.

Feel free to ask any doubt on this.